# How to determine whether GPS position has been acquired on android?

Tags: android, gps

Let's say I have a button which calls another activity only if the system knows the EXACT user's location. I made a dialog to ask the user to turn on GPS if it's disabled, but when the user enables GPS and pushes the button again, I will probably not have the exact location yet. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: please explain the last part of your question better.. more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a LocationListener, and wait for the callback. It is pretty well described in the api [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html):

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     // When you get here you have a location...
     useTheNewLocationToEnableTheButton(location); 
  }

  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for [GpsStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html) events, to make sure that user actually enabled GPS (GPS_EVENT_STARTED), and to be notified when GPS gets position fix (GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX).

Comment: +1 for GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX event.  I didn't know about this, very useful.  The only problem is that if you are indoors or unable to somehow receive a good GPS signal, you could be waiting a long time for this event.

Comment: In this case you should have some kind of timeouts: if gps fix is not acquired within some timeframe than notify user about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know coordinates, the best way is to display a [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) while retrieving a location and, when you got it, dismiss ProgressDialog and launch your activity.

```
final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //here you can get coordinates via location.getLongitude() and
    //location.getLatitude() methods, dismiss the progress dialog and
    //start your activity
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```